# Capture Telnet output to a file by running in the background

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I am having a linux powered board on which I wanted to capture the telnet output to a file. I tried doing it as shown below-

```
telnet localhost xxxx >> /mnt/sd-xxx/log/file.txt &
```

as well as

```
telnet localhost xxxx | tee /mnt/sd-xxx/log/file.txt &
```

and

```
telnet localhost xxxx -f /mnt/sd-xxx/log/file.txt &
```

But it's unable to go in background in all of the above cases. I also tried to keep it in a script,but this also doesn't work and the program crashes. How can I capture the telnet output and redirect to a file by running it as a background process.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Try with netcat to port 23. It will match your needs better than telnet

Comment: You can use & at the end of the command to run it in background

like 
./myscript&

Comment: @navand I already tried putting & at the end of script but it is crashing when enter key is pressed.

Comment: per your comment on the `curl` answer, 'Stopped (tty input)', its expecting input. You have to replicate any inputs that you would normally type so try this `{ echo myUserID ; echo myPswd ; } | telnet .... > ... & ` Good luck.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried curl?

```
curl telnet://localhost:xxxx >> /mnt/sd-xxx/log/file.txt &
```

Comment: I am getting following message:                                               [1] + Stopped (tty input)        curl telnet://localhost:xxxx 1>>a.txt